# Can a template simplify the adding of one or more spans in FormattedString in FormattedText to Labels?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's an example of what I need to do now. Sometimes I have one span, sometimes more.

```
<Label>
   <Label.FormattedText>
      <FormattedString>
         <Span Text="Hello " />
         <Span Text="Hello " />
         <Span Text=" Some more text." />
      </FormattedString>
   </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

Is there any way that this could be accomplished with a template so the XAML needed was more like this:

```
<template:FormattedLabel>
   <Span Text="Hello " />
   <Span Text="Hello " />
   <Span Text=" Some more text." />
</template:FormattedLabel>
```

or

```
<template:FormattedLabel>
   <Span Text="Hello " />
</template:FormattedLabel>
```

Note that I have looked into custom controls but as far as I see I cannot find a way to make these accept some inside content which in this case would be one or more spans.

What I was hoping for was a template **like this** which is what I used for content pages:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=J" 
   xmlns:t="clr-namespace:J.Templates" 
   x:Class="Japanese.Templates.ContentScrollable" 
   x:Name="ContentPage" >
   <ContentPage.Content>
       <t:Stack Orientation="Vertical">
          <ScrollView x:Name="scroll">
             <ContentView Content="{Binding Source={x:Reference ContentPage}, Path=InnerContent}" 
                         Margin="{DynamicResource PageMargin}" />
          </ScrollView>
       </t:Stack>
   </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

With its back end in C#

```
public partial class ContentScrollable : ContentPage
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty InnerContentProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(InnerContent), typeof(View), typeof(ContentScrollable));

    public View InnerContent
    {
        get => (View)this.GetValue(InnerContentProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(InnerContentProperty, value);
    }

    public ContentScrollable()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can accomplish what I am looking for?

Comment: Do not delete and report the same question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55663345/can-a-template-simplify-the-adding-of-spans-in-formattedstring-in-formattedtext

Comment: "Please don't just leave a link to custom controls in the answer" - such an answer would be deleted by the Review Queue anyway, for being a link-only answer, so I have removed it for brevity. If you want to give some guidance on technical constraints on answers, you can add it back again, but it would benefit from an explanation of what your constraint is.

Answer (score -2):

Using Javascript you can add or remove spans on the go

FormattedStrings could also be defined via code

```
const label = new Label();

const firstLabelSpan = new Span();
firstLabelSpan.text = "Formatted String ";
const secondLabelSpan = new Span();
secondLabelSpan.text = "Label";

const formattedStringLabel = new FormattedString();
formattedStringLabel.spans.push(firstLabelSpan);
formattedStringLabel.spans.push(secondLabelSpan);

label.formattedText = formattedStringLabel;
```

programmatically you can push or pop spans and manage labels

Comment: This is a Xamarin question.  There is no javascript with Xamarin.